# Add multiple files using Django admin inline formset

Tags: javascript, django, upload

In the admin portion of my Django app I want to extend how an existing inline formset works.  Currently, I have an inline formset for images with 2 fields - `name` and `image`.  That model looks similar to this:

**models.py**

```
class Slideshow(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=200,upload_to=destination)
    ...
```

Now, in Django admin, I can click "Add another" in my inline, and that adds another block of name and image fields to the inline formset.  In that form I can select "Choose file" and add an image file (and optionally a name), click Save and all works well using the existing Django admin functionality.

Is there a way for me to add multiple image files at once to this existing inline formset?  Say using an HTML multiple file selection?

**Example formset row with sample data**

```
<div class="grp-module grp-tbody has_original grp-dynamic-form" id="asset_set0">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><b>asset #1</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; sample-banner-444-fff.gif</h3>
    <div class="grp-tr">

        <div class="grp-td name ">
            <input class="vTextField" id="id_asset_set-0-name" maxlength="200" name="asset_set-0-name" type="text" value="test asset">
        </div>

        <div class="grp-td file ">
            <p class="file-upload">Currently: <a href="https://converse-portal-test.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_files/2014/02/13/10/52/1392317533/sample-banner-444-fff.gif?Signature=MBuCwPmV375gFfWDPKY06xP78bQ%3D&amp;Expires=1394664278&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIMAKOOSEMJWWDRDA">asset_files/2014/02/13/10/52/1392317533/sample-banner-444-fff.gif</a> <br>Change: <input id="id_asset_set-0-file" name="asset_set-0-file" type="file"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="grp-td grp-tools-container">
            <ul class="grp-tools"><li class="grp-delete-handler-container"><input id="id_asset_set-0-DELETE" name="asset_set-0-DELETE" type="checkbox"><a href="javascript://" class="grp-icon grp-delete-handler" title="Delete Item"></a></li></ul>
        </div>

        <input id="id_asset_set-0-campaign" name="asset_set-0-campaign" type="hidden" value="25">
        <input id="id_asset_set-0-id" name="asset_set-0-id" type="hidden" value="71">

    </div>
</div>
```

**Example formset row without data**

```
<div class="grp-module grp-tbody grp-dynamic-form" id="asset_set1">    
    <h3 style="display: none;"><b>asset #2</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>
    <div class="grp-tr">

        <div class="grp-td name ">
            <input class="vTextField" id="id_asset_set-1-name" maxlength="200" name="asset_set-1-name" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="grp-td file ">
                <input id="id_asset_set-1-file" name="asset_set-1-file" type="file">
        </div>

        <div class="grp-td grp-tools-container">
            <ul class="grp-tools"><li><a href="javascript://" class="grp-icon grp-remove-handler" title="Delete Item"></a></li></ul>
        </div>

        <input id="id_asset_set-1-campaign" name="asset_set-1-campaign" type="hidden" value="25">
        <input id="id_asset_set-1-id" name="asset_set-1-id" type="hidden">
    </div>
</div>
```

*By the way, I have reviewed a few other apps, [filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer) and [photologue](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue) for example, that offer similar functionality at the cost of including several other features that may or may not affect the rest of my application.*

Comment: Can you include the code around the existing inline formset?

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the code around the existing inline formset.  I've offered what it looks like with and without sample post data.